# PS1 problem, cmd is looping

Tags: command-line, bash, ps1

I've set `PS1` to the following value:

```
PS1="\033[0;37m[\033[1;33m\w\033[0;37m]\n\t \[[34m\]\u\033[0;37m@\[[34m\]\[[1m\]\h\[(B[m\] $"
```

The problem is that any command spanning more than a line loops around and don't generate a new line. So I overwrite the line that I already have typed. What is wrong with the `PS1`?

Comment: that's not even a valid command, bash waiting for more input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-printing characters in the prompt need to be surrounded by `\[` and `\]` so that bash can properly track the length of the prompt and accommodate lines that go beyond the edge of the terminal.

Comment: SO I should add before and after which parts of the line?

Comment: You add it before and after the parts that don't print, as many times as required.

Comment: But the line do print, but when i type in a long command it loops.

Comment: CHARACTERS. Try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now :) `PS1="\033[0;37m[\033[1;33m\[\w\]\033[0;37m]\[\n\]\[\t\] \[${tRandColor}\]\[\u\]\033[0;37m@\[${tRandColor}\]\[${tBold}\]\[\h\]\[${tReset}\] \$`