# Terminal strangeness after installing Xcode on Lion

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, bash, shell

I have a simple custom bash prompt:

```
PS1="\[\e[47;1;30m\]\u@\h [\W] \!\[\e[0;32m\]$\[\e[0m\]"
```

It worked great under Snow Leopard, and worked great in Lion *until I installed Xcode*. I installed Xcode 3 (without *System Tools* or *Unix Development*) and then Xcode 4.1.1.

Now, the caret starts in the middle of the prompt.

[image]

And, bash fails completely at line wrapping.

[image]

If I remove [`\[` and `\]`](https://superuser.com/questions/311511/ps1-problem-cmd-is-looping), the caret starts in the right place but line wrapping doesn't happen at all.

Worse, `man` is broken:

```
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
-  (press RETURN)
```

What happened to my terminal when I installed Xcode? Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this better?

---

In response to [Turadg’s answer](https://superuser.com/questions/327791/terminal-strangeness-after-installing-xcode-on-lion/339214#339214): `diff` reports that these directories were missing from my terminfo folder, but present in that of a fresh Lion install (all the others were identical):

> 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 4c, 4d, 4e, 50, 51, 58, 66, 6a, 7a

Comment: Did `export TERM=xterm` fix this problem for you Sid?

Comment: Hey, @chown. See my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem after installing Xcode 4.1. It appears to have replaced `/usr/share/terminfo` and left out the descriptor for `xterm-256color`, the default for Lion terminals.

You can verify this this is the case on your system with:

`infocmp xterm-256color`

That should return a descriptor. If it doesn't, it's missing from `/usr/share/terminfo/78`.

One way to get back to a working terminal is to set "TERM=xterm-color", but then you lose the expanded features of `xterm-256color`. What I did was restore `/usr/share/terminfo` from a backup (thanks Time Machine). If you don't have a backup, you can copy it from another machine. For more details, see these [example commands](http://marcoschuh.de/wp/?p=873).

Comment: Looks like this is it. A number of directories were missing from my `/usr/share/terminfo` but present on a fresh install of Lion. Now I just wonder, what’s going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Install iTerm2, and the first thing it did upon being launched was to advise me that the configuration for xterm-256colors was missing, and offered to install it. This repaired the terminal display problems (which is now virtually a moot point as iTerm2 is outstanding).

Comment: Of all the other answers, this was the only one that worked. Simple, flawless, painless. Thank you, this was driving me nuts.

Comment: There should probably be a more straight forward answer to this problem, but this was easy and worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

In ~/.bashrc or /etc/bashrc put:

```
export TERM=xterm
## or export TERM=xterm-color
```

Then type:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
source /etc/bashrc
```

If you have both files, put it in your ~/.bashrc and source the one in your ~.

This same exact thing happened to me yesterday when I uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode/developer-tools and it seems that the env variable TERM got changed to "xterm-256color" which has quite a diff from xterm-color:

```
[ 09:32 root@MacBook-Air ~ ]# infocmp -I xterm-256color > ~/xterm-256color.src
[ 09:32 root@MacBook-Air ~ ]# infocmp -I xterm-color > ~/xterm-color.src
[ 09:33 root@MacBook-Air ~ ]# diff xterm-color.src xterm-256color.src
1,4c1,4
< # Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /opt/local/share/terminfo/78/xterm-color
< xterm-color|xterm terminal emulator (X Window System),
<   am, bce, xenl, km, mir, msgr, npc, mc5i,
<   cols#80, it#8, lines#24, colors#8, pairs#64,
---
> # Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /opt/local/share/terminfo/78/xterm-256color
> xterm-256color|xterm with 256 colors,
>   am, bce, ccc, xenl, km, mir, msgr, npc, mc5i,
>   cols#80, it#8, lines#24, colors#256, pairs#32767,
12,15c12,17
<   smir=\E[4h, rev=\E[7m, invis=\E[8m, smso=\E[7m, smul=\E[4m,
<   ech=\E[%p1%dX, rmacs=\E(B, rmam=\E[?7l, sgr0=\E(B\E[m,
<   rmir=\E[4l, rmso=\E[27m, rmul=\E[24m,
<   flash=\E[?5h$<100/>\E[?5l, is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>,
---
>   smcup=\E[?1049h, smir=\E[4h, rev=\E[7m, invis=\E[8m,
>   smso=\E[7m, smul=\E[4m, ech=\E[%p1%dX, rmacs=\E(B,
>   rmam=\E[?7l, sgr0=\E(B\E[m, rmcup=\E[?1049l, rmir=\E[4l,
>   rmso=\E[27m, rmul=\E[24m, flash=\E[?5h$<100/>\E[?5l,
>   is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>,
>   initc=\E]4;%p1%d;rgb\:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\E\\,
39,45c41,49
<   smkx=\E[?1h\E=, rmm=\E[?1034l, smm=\E[?1034h,
<   op=\E[39;49m, dch=\E[%p1%dP, dl=\E[%p1%dM, cud=\E[%p1%dB,
<   ich=\E[%p1%d@, indn=\E[%p1%dS, il=\E[%p1%dL,
<   cub=\E[%p1%dD, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, rin=\E[%p1%dT,
<   cuu=\E[%p1%dA, mc0=\E[i, mc4=\E[4i, mc5=\E[5i, rs1=\Ec,
<   rs2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>, rc=\E8, vpa=\E[%i%p1%dd,
<   sc=\E7, ind=^J, ri=\EM, setab=\E[4%p1%dm, setaf=\E[3%p1%dm,
---
>   smkx=\E[?1h\E=, meml=\El, memu=\Em, rmm=\E[?1034l,
>   smm=\E[?1034h, op=\E[39;49m, dch=\E[%p1%dP, dl=\E[%p1%dM,
>   cud=\E[%p1%dB, ich=\E[%p1%d@, indn=\E[%p1%dS,
>   il=\E[%p1%dL, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cuf=\E[%p1%dC,
>   rin=\E[%p1%dT, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, mc0=\E[i, mc4=\E[4i,
>   mc5=\E[5i, rs1=\Ec, rs2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>, rc=\E8,
>   vpa=\E[%i%p1%dd, sc=\E7, ind=^J, ri=\EM,
>   setab=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t4%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;%p1%d%;m,
>   setaf=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;%p1%d%;m,
47,48d50
<   setb=\E[4%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m,
<   setf=\E[3%?%p1%{1}%=%t4%e%p1%{3}%=%t6%e%p1%{4}%=%t1%e%p1%{6}%=%t3%e%p1%d%;m,
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks, @chown, but I don't think this is the right solution. `TERM` gets set by Terminal itself based on your preferences (you set it on a per-configuration basis in the settings tab), so you should never need to override it. Also, Lion uses `xterm-256color` by default, which works fine on an out-of-box computer.

Comment: Maybe the configuration got changed for the xterm-256color when xCode was installed.  I'll look into some more.  Btw, I just found out about iTerm, so superior to Terminal!  I would highly recommend it.