# Linux: coloring bash prompt will break carriage return

Tags: bash, terminal, bashrc, ubuntu-11.10, ps1

When I try to colorize the `bash` prompt like this:

```
export PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m "
```

it breaks the carriage return (instead of going to a new line when line is full, it starts in the same line and erases the input text).

If I remove the color sequence it works fine.
I use Ubuntu 11.10 and terminal (guake has the same bug too).

Comment: Strange. It works w/o any problem on RedHat 5 and Mac OS X

Comment: possible duplicate of [PS1 problem, cmd is looping](http://superuser.com/questions/311511/ps1-problem-cmd-is-looping)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You must wrap all escape sequences between `\[` and `\]` in order for 'readline' to correctly calculate the prompt's visible length. Without them, 'readline' thinks the prompt is longer than it is, and doesn't know when the text reaches the margin.

```
PS1="\[\e[;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$ \[\e[m\]"
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!! i was trying to find some documentation on it in the official docs but couldnt -- the 'stock' color prompt does employ this 'trick' and I had a hard time at first figuring out what exactly it was for, so thanks for clearing that up --- btw i did actually find the documentation source in 'man readline 3' around line 684 and it says that this is actually called 'skip-csi-sequence' for those who want to know where the documentation on this is. I don't think i would have found it without you pointing me to readline(3) even though i knew about it before-failed to make the connection.

Comment: What does "wrap" mean? Do you mean wrap the whole thing *IN* a `\[`, `\]`? I guess so, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: @osirisgothra: The documentation is actually talking about a different thing – `skip-csi-sequence` is meant to suppress **input** sequences generated by special keys.

Comment: @MaxHowell you have to wrap each `\e[xxm` sequence, not the whole string.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I just replaced `\e[39m` with `\[\e[;39m\]` and it works fine

Comment: Note that `\e[;39m` expands to `\e[0;39m` which means "reset all formatting, _then_ set color to 39". It's good in prompts, but it is not in any way related to my post about `\[ \]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was going crazy debugging this...

Comment: During reviews, a new user posted the following as an answer, so I am converting to a comment: Accepted answer worked for me, but I wanted to keep the $ that the prompts ends in for normal users as opposed to root (then it ends in #).  So I used: `PS1="\[\e[;31m\][\u@\h \W]\$ \[\e[m\]\[\$\]"`

Comment: That's not a good change though, it results in the opposite problem (as the `\$` is visible it must not be bracketed). I think they actually wanted to just change the existing `\$` to `\\$`, the new brackets at the end didn't need to be added.

Answer (score 1):

the [ and ] tip worked on bash on OS X 10.8.2 too.

I use:

> PS1="[\e[0;37m\W\$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep -e '* ' | sed 's/^..(.*)/{\1}/') \$  \e[m ]"

which shows me my current git branch in use.

Comment: Do you know about "__git_ps1" ?

Comment: nopes. what magical thing will it do?