# How can I fix my custom PS1 to wrap a long command over multiple lines instead of a single line?

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I'm trying to customize my bash prompt on Mac OS X. Here is what I put in .bash_profile:

```
$ cat .bash_profile
export PS1="\e[0;36m\u : \W \$\e[m "
#...
```

I got the prompt I wanted but when I enter a long command, all is written on a single line. At the end of line, it starts back at the beginning.

How can I improve my custom PS1 to wrap long commands over to the next line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux: coloring bash prompt will broke carriage return](http://superuser.com/questions/367275/linux-coloring-bash-prompt-will-broke-carriage-return)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the formatting sequences that will not actually be printed in `\[` and `\]` so that the length calculations don't break. More about it [here](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3292/22317) in the section *Colors*.

Comment: It's `\[` `\]` for the calculations; `\e[` is the formatting sequence itself.

Comment: @grawity Thanks. Got it right in the linked post, at least :-)