# Putty history access weird behavior

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, terminal, putty

I'm using PuTTY v0.78 on a Win10 host, connecting to Ubuntu v22.04. After I've pasted any command into the PuTTY terminal, when I scroll though the history using <kbd>↑</kbd>, I can't scroll up to the prompt sign at the very beginning of the content since the cursor will stop unexpectedly on an arbitrary character while scrolling: [image: illustration]

What could cause this problem and how do I fix it? It's very annoying not being able to move the cursor to the first char in command taken from history!

Comment: The history has nothing to do with PuTTY, the program is probably not to blame. Is the shell Bash? What is the output of `declare -p PS1`? Does this help? [coloring bash prompt will break carriage return](https://superuser.com/q/367275/432690)